# What will change when workstations will have ARM Machine Learning Processors onboard?

Tags: machine-learning, performance

lately we read that many manufacturers are forcing ARM architectures to be used on future workstations. One of ARM's recent announcements is a [machine learning processor](https://www.arm.com/products/silicon-ip-cpu/machine-learning/arm-ml-processor). What will change in terms of computing performance if ARM architectures become new standard, and these kinds of ML-focused chips are found in most devices?

Answer (score 1):

It is not clear to me that much will change.

- ARM makes many devices, mostly designed to consume as little power as possible. My guess is that most workstations will not contain ARM's ML processor, even if they contain an ARM CPU.
- ARM's ML processor can do machine learning. It is specifically optimized for training convolutional deep neural networks, and it is a bit faster that most existing non-purpose built chips, especially for its price. In practice, chips like this one should make ML a bit cheaper and faster, but it's not a breakthrough product. This just looks like the next iteration of [Moore's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore%27s_law).